# NSubstitute object can't use Returns() extension method

Tags: .net, vb.net, nunit, nsubstitute

I'm working on VB project in our company. It's quite old, but under active development. Recently we introduced Unit Tests, new features must be covered, we're also picking some old features if we have spare time. We're using NUnit 3.9 and NSubstitute 2.0.3, test project targets .NET Framework 3.5.

**Update:** As Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen suggested, I prepared MCV for this question, here's the code which fails:

```
Dim dataReaderSubstitute As IDataReader = Substitute.For(Of IDataReader)()
dataReaderSubstitute.GetValue(0).Returns(email) 'test fails here
```

To make sure that problem still exists in newest version of NSubstitute and can be quickly reproduced, I created separate project in .net 4.6.2 with NUnit 3.9.0 and NSubstitute 3.1.0

```
Imports NUnit.Framework
Imports NSubstitute

<TestFixture> Public Class SubstituteProblemTest

Private Shared ReadOnly Iterator Property PersonTestData() As IEnumerable(Of TestCaseData)
    Get
        Yield New TestCaseData("john.smith@domain.com")
    End Get
End Property

<Test, TestCaseSource("PersonTestData")> Public Sub SubstituteProblem(ByVal email As String)
    Dim dataReaderSubstitute As IDataReader = Substitute.For(Of IDataReader)()
    dataReaderSubstitute.GetValue(0).Returns(email) 'test fails here
End Sub

End Class
```

The problem is that I get an error in second line of `SubstituteProblem` method:

> Test Name:      SubstituteProblem("john.smith@domain.com") 
>   Test FullName:  NSubstituteTest.SubstituteProblemTest.SubstituteProblem("john.smith@domain.com") 
>   Test Source:    c:\git\NSubstituteTest\NSubstituteTest\SubstituteProblemTest.vb : line 12 
>   Test Outcome:   Failed 
>   Test Duration:  0:00:00.368
>
> Result Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object variable or With block variable not set. 
>   Result StackTrace: 
>   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container..ctor(Object Instance) 
>      at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateCall(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn) 
>      at NSubstituteTest.SubstituteProblemTest.SubstituteProblem(String forename) in c:\git\NSubstituteTest\NSubstituteTest\SubstituteProblemTest.vb:line 14

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I was following example from NSubstitute website https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/set-return-value/. Why does Returns method couldn't change object created by NSubstitute?

Comment: What is the type of `_databaseCommandFactorySubstitute`? Can you please add that to the question?

Comment: Did you configure what `_databaseCommandFactorySubstitute.Create()` should return?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen `_databaseCommandFactorySubstitute.Create()` returns NSubstitute proxy which inherits IDatabaseCommand, this is what I expected. The problem is in earlier lines: `dataReaderSubstitute.GetValue(0).Returns(email)`

Comment: You probably need to narrow it down to a [mcve], a simple test I did here doesn't have a problem with substituting GetValue return value, though that's an awfully old version of NSubstitute.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlse I changed my question a bit, let me know if it's clear

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that was my mistake. I was not aware of something called "Late Binding", which is a feature of Visual Basic language. When I tried to use `Returns` method on instance of type `Object`, compiler tried to execute method as if it was part of class, not extension. So I had to execute extension method explicitly:

```
Dim dataReaderSubstitute As IDataReader = Substitute.For(Of IDataReader)()
SubstituteExtensions.Returns(dataReaderSubstitute.GetValue(0), email)
```